# MySQL Full Text Search where in

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I'm trying to create a full text search with MySQL. My query looks like this.

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE MATCH (name, first_name, street, city)
                              AGAINST ('$parameter' IN boolean MODE)
```

If I query for example `Peter` everything works fine. But if I type only the start of my search string (`Pete`) I get an empty result.

How can I get the rows which contains my string and not only the rows where the string is exactly the same?

Answer (score 1):

use `NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE`

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE MATCH (name, first_name, street, city) AGAINST ('$parameter' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

Natural language full-text search interprets the search string as a free text (natural human language) and no special operators are required. Full-text searches are natural language searches if the IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE modifier (see the following syntax) is given or not. MATCH() function searches a string against a text collection (A set of one or more columns included in a FULLTEXT index.). For each row in the table, MATCH() returns a relevance value; that is, a similarity measure between the search string (given as the argument to AGAINST() function) and the text in that row in the columns named in the MATCH() list

Comment: Thank you! But for example I have a entry with the value ‘Peter’ and I get only a result if the the search string is also ‘Peter’. I want also a result if I type ‘Pete’ or ‘eter’ and so on.

Comment: Yes i‘ve tryed it

Comment: I want to get the most relevant row on the first and least relevant on the last row, how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH (...) AGAINST ('$parameter*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

MATCH (...) AGAINST ('Pete*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

The wildcard `*` can be put at the *end* of string to match anything beginning with it.  That will match

```
Pete
Peter
petechiae
peteforamerica
petethecatbooks
péteux
```